# What whole number when divide by 3,4,5 gives as a remainder of 1?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

What whole number (integer $\geq 0$) when divide by 3,4,5 gives as a remainder of 1?

please help me solve the question I have it as a homework due tomorrow. I will be very grateful for the one that answers me.

Comment: So that number minus $1$ is divisible by $3,4,5$.

Comment: What is wrong with $1$?

Answer (score 5):

Hint: Multiply the three numbers to find the *least common multiple* of $3,\,4,\, 5$ $(\operatorname{lcm} (3, 4, 5))$ then add 1:

$$3 \cdot 4\cdot 5 +1$$